# Выделение ячеек таблицы

Tags: jquery, css

Суть вопроса в чем, есть таблица, которая состоит из двух столбцов. При клике по ячейке она изменяет цвет. Нужно, чтобы при в каждой колонке можно было бы выделить только одну ячейку.

Тоесть например был клик по ячейки номер 2, в первой колонке, она перекрасилась, потом клик по ячейки номер 5, в тойжэ колнонке, ячейка номер два возвращяет свой начальный цвет, а ячейка номер 5 перекаршивается. Тоже и с второй колонкой.

Просто перекрашивание ячейки сделал, а вот как сделать описаное выше?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('click');
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
.click {
    background-color:green;
}
</style>

<table class="bordered">
<tr>
<td class="lc" id="id1" >Text1</td>
<td  class="rc" id="id2">Text2</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td class="lc" id="id3" >Text3</td>
<td  class="rc" id="id4">Text4</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td class="lc" id="id5" >Text5</td>
<td  class="rc" id="id6">Text6</td>
</tr> 
.....
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смысл в том, что при клике на ячейку, со всех ячеек, кроме кликнутой, снимается класс click, в то время как на кликнутую он ставится/снимается

```
$('td').click(function () {
    $('td').not($(this).toggleClass('click')).removeClass('click');
});
```

И еще совет: используйте делегирование события. То есть вместо того, чтобы навешивать обработчик на каждую ячейку таблицы, навешивайте его на всю таблицу, и определяйте, клик по какому элементу вам нужно отслеживать:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function () {
    $('td').not($(this).toggleClass('click')).removeClass('click');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Теперь вы у всех ячеек, чей индекc совпадает с кликнутой ячейкой, удаляете класс click. Таким образом в одной колонке всегда будет выделена только одна ячейка:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('td').not(this).filter(function() {
        return $(this).index() == index;
    }).removeClass('click');
    $(this).toggleClass('click');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но нюанс, клик по ячейке в первой колонке, потом клик по ячейки второй колонки, первая колонка должны остатся закрашеной, а она возвращает первоначальной цвет.

Тоесть нужно выделить дв ячейки, одна в первой колонке, вторая в другой.

Comment: @arashvg ну вам нужно просто ограничить область поиска тега td, типа: 

    $('td', $(this).closest('table')).....

Comment: Второй код не работает (((

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @arashvg я неправильно прочитал, мой только для разных таблиц. У господина @andreyqin ответ правильный: http://jsfiddle.net/N2EGr/
Только чтобы метод toggle работал правильно, я немножко добавил своего.

Comment: @lampa, не учел, спасибо за исправление.

Comment: Спасибо всем!!! Все работает, скажу честно в  Jquery и java полный ноль! Выручили!!! Еще раз спасибо!